# Random().nextInt() not zero-based numbering?

Tags: java, kotlin

```
import java.util.*
```

I'm trying to generate a random string from my array:

```
val days = arrayOf("Tuesday", "Thursday", "Saturday")
val chosenDay = days[Random().nextInt(2)]
```

However `days[Random().nextInt(2)]` only seems to return Tuesday and Thursday. I couldn't find the answer anywhere but why is `nextInt()` not using zero-based numbering?

I changed it to `days[Random().nextInt(3)]` and now it's working fine.

Comment: The argument to `nextInt()` specifies the excluded upper bound. See the Javadoc.

Comment: *"why is nextInt() not using zero-based numbering?"* It is! Please, **read the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.random/-random/next-int.html)**: *"Generates an `Int` random value uniformly distributed between `0` (inclusive) and the specified `until` bound (**exclusive**)."* --- E.g. `nextInt(8)` returns numbers 0-7 (excluding 8), so definitely zero-based.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not about zero- or one-based indexing (if it was, you would only get `"Thursday"` or `"Saturday"`), but that `nextInt` takes the *exclusive* upper bound. That is, `nextInt(3)` returns a number less than 3.

This is a convention compatible with zero-indexing, in fact, since it means you can use the array's length as the upper bound to get a random element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

As is typical for Kotlin, there are a lot of extension functions for typical use cases. Like here, [getting a random element](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/random.html) from an array or a collection.

In your case, the simplest code is:

```
val chosenDay = days.random()
```

Or, if you need more control about the randomness:

```
val chosenDay = days.random(Random(12345))   // for testing
```

The reason that `Random.nextInt(n)` generates a zero-based random number is that it can be conveniently used in expressions like this:

```
val chosenDay = days[Random().nextInt(days.size)]
```

Comment: I am not the one who downvoted, in fact with a few minor changes I would upvote because using .random() is in my eyes the best way to get a random element from an Array. Problems: public fun <T> Array<out T>.random(random: Random): T takes a kotlin.random.Random as paramter (not java.util.Random). (code line 2) You should generally use Kotlin's Random since it's platform independent (code line 3).